# How to handle error and successful reply in SimpleWebServiceOutboundGateway?

Tags: spring-integration

I am new to Spring-Integration. I have implemented SOAP web-service using SimpleWebServiceOutboundGateway and I am trying to handle error case for this web service. My problem is as under:

For example, I got the web-service call from some server with some data (say some header information), I processed it and I am trying to respond to same server with some data (say with ID of newly created data in database). If the calling server is not reachable then error will be thrown and ***I want to store the ID of newly created data and header information from the original service call*** in the database.

How can I achieve it?

Answer (score 0):

See [Adding Behavior to Endpoints](https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/messaging-endpoints-chapter.html#message-handler-advice-chain) - specifically, an `ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice`.